# ftplib RETR a small file stuck

Tags: python, aws-lambda, ftplib

Ok, first things first - there is little configuration available on this FTP; it is part of an industrial HMI control panel. I have tested via Filezilla the ability to download a file without PASV and it works fine. Here is the verbose from filezilla - you can see it takes about 1 second because we're talking kilobytes here.

```
Status: Starting download of /USB_Pen_Memory/Log/Data Log Trend_Ops_Data_Log_230802.txt
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    CWD /USB_Pen_Memory/Log
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   250 CWD command successful.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Reset(0) in state 2
Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 1
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SetAsyncRequestReply
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 1
Command:    TYPE A
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   200 Type set to A.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    PASV
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   502 Invalid command.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    PORT 192,168,0,41,204,135
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   200 PORT command successful.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
Command:    RETR Data Log Trend_Ops_Data_Log_230802.txt
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnAccept(0)
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for Data Log Trend_Ops_Data_Log_230802.txt.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   226 Transfer complete.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 8
Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Reset(0) in state 8
Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 7
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::Reset(0) in state 7
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 48.20 KB in 1 second
```

Here is my code in AWS Lambda Python version 3.10

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
from io import BytesIO
import ftplib
import logging
import os
import csv
import time
import boto3
import logging

def ftp_connection(HOST, USER, PASS):
    
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(source_address=())
    ftp.connect(HOST)
    ftp.login(USER,PASS)
    ftp.set_pasv(False)
    ftp.set_debuglevel(1)

    return ftp

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    yesterday = dt.strftime(dt.today() - timedelta (days = 1), '%y%m%d')
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", time.gmtime())
    config_s3_bucket_name = os.environ['S3_CONFIG_LOC']
    data_s3_bucket_name = os.environ['S3_DATA_LOC']
    config_file_key = 'ftp_config.csv'
    crawler_name = 'FTPLogs'

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
    logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

    # Step 1: Connect to S3 and download the config file
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
    config_file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=config_s3_bucket_name, Key=config_file_key)
    config_file_data = config_file_obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
    config_reader = csv.DictReader(config_file_data)

    # Step 2: Loop through each row in the config file and load latest log to s3
    for row in config_reader:
        ftp_site_name = row['ftp_site_name']
        ftp_ip = row['ftp_ip_address']
        ftp_username = row['ftp_username']
        ftp_password = row['ftp_password']
        file_directory = row['ftp_log_directory']
        filename_convention = row['filename_convention']

        conn = ftp_connection(ftp_ip, ftp_username, ftp_password)

        #change the directory
        conn.cwd(file_directory)

        try :
                
            with BytesIO() as output_buffer:
                conn.transfercmd('RETR ' + filename_convention + yesterday + '.txt', output_buffer.write)
                output_buffer.write(f',{ftp_site_name},{timestamp}\n'.encode('utf-8'))
                output_buffer.seek(0)

                s3_key = f'{ftp_site_name}/dt={timestamp}/{latest_csv_file}'
                s3.upload_fileobj(output_buffer, Bucket=data_s3_bucket_name, Key=s3_key)


            # Close file and connection
            local_file.close()
            conn.close()

            # Upload the file from the local temporary directory to S3
            s3 = boto3.client('s3')
            s3_key = f'dt={timestamp}/{filename_convention}{yesterday}.txt'
            s3.upload_file(local_temp_file, Bucket=data_s3_bucket_name, Key=s3_key)
        
        #Log any error
        except ftplib.all_errors as e :

            logger.error(str(e))
            continue

        logging.shutdown()

    glue = boto3.client('glue', config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4')) 
    glue.start_crawler(Name=crawler_name)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Function executed successfully. Crawler Started'
    }
```

Problem is it just sits:

```
2023-08-02T19:58:15.620-07:00   *cmd* 'CWD /USB_Pen_Memory/Log'

2023-08-02T19:58:15.675-07:00   *resp* '250 CWD command successful.'

2023-08-02T19:58:15.676-07:00   *cmd* 'PORT 169,254,76,1,132,71'

2023-08-02T19:58:15.730-07:00   *resp* '200 PORT command successful.'

2023-08-02T19:58:15.730-07:00   *cmd* 'REST <built-in method write of _io.BytesIO object at 0x7f4ff15a53a0>'

2023-08-02T19:58:15.790-07:00   *resp* '350 Restarting at 0.'

2023-08-02T19:58:15.790-07:00   *cmd* 'RETR Data Log Trend_Ops_Data_Log_230801.txt'

2023-08-02T20:00:15.274-07:00   2023-08-03T03:00:15.273Z f68b8176-a188-4a50-ae45-6c12167dcad6 Task timed out after 120.05 seconds
```

the PORT has caught my eye here as it stands out as different than what is shown from filezilla. I have tried retrbinary and transfercmd; both are the same. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Since Tim pointed out that s3 is slow, here is the version I have which attempts to download to local tmp which is seeing the same exact problem. Also I just remembered that I have two sites with different IPs and both are showing the same thing. This strange unrouteable PORT IP.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
from io import BytesIO
import ftplib
import logging
import os
import csv
import time
import boto3
import logging

def ftp_connection(HOST, USER, PASS):
    
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(source_address=())
    ftp.connect(HOST)
    ftp.login(USER,PASS)
    ftp.set_pasv(False)
    ftp.set_debuglevel(1)

    return ftp

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    yesterday = dt.strftime(dt.today() - timedelta (days = 1), '%y%m%d')
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", time.gmtime())
    config_s3_bucket_name = os.environ['S3_CONFIG_LOC']
    data_s3_bucket_name = os.environ['S3_DATA_LOC']
    config_file_key = 'ftp_config.csv'
    crawler_name = 'FTPLogs'

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
    logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

    # Step 1: Connect to S3 and download the config file
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
    config_file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=config_s3_bucket_name, Key=config_file_key)
    config_file_data = config_file_obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
    config_reader = csv.DictReader(config_file_data)

    # Step 2: Loop through each row in the config file
    for row in config_reader:
        ftp_site_name = row['ftp_site_name']
        ftp_ip = row['ftp_ip_address']
        ftp_username = row['ftp_username']
        ftp_password = row['ftp_password']
        file_directory = row['ftp_log_directory']
        filename_convention = row['filename_convention']

        conn = ftp_connection(ftp_ip, ftp_username, ftp_password)

        #change the directory
        conn.cwd(file_directory)

        try :
            
            # Define the local temporary directory
            local_temp_directory = '/tmp'
            os.makedirs(local_temp_directory, exist_ok=True)

            # Define the local temporary file path
            local_temp_file = os.path.join(local_temp_directory, f'{filename_convention}{yesterday}.txt')

            # Download the file to the local temporary directory
            with open(local_temp_file, 'wb') as local_file:
                conn.retrbinary(f'RETR {filename_convention}{yesterday}.txt', local_file.write)
                local_file.write(f',{ftp_site_name},{timestamp}\n'.encode('utf-8'))

            # Close file and connection
            local_file.close()
            conn.close()

            # Upload the file from the local temporary directory to S3
            s3 = boto3.client('s3')
            s3_key = f'dt={timestamp}/{filename_convention}{yesterday}.txt'
            s3.upload_file(local_temp_file, Bucket=data_s3_bucket_name, Key=s3_key)
        
        #Log any error
        except ftplib.all_errors as e :

            logger.error(str(e))
            continue

        logging.shutdown()

    glue = boto3.client('glue', config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4')) 
    glue.start_crawler(Name=crawler_name)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Function executed successfully. Crawler Started'
    }
```

EDIT 3:

Yes I used prints because... that is really all.

```
    # Download the file to the local temporary directory
    with open(local_temp_file, 'wb') as local_file:
        print('opened local file')
        conn.retrbinary(f'RETR {filename_convention}{yesterday}.txt', local_file.write)
        print('{filename_convention}{yesterday} written to local tmp')
        local_file.write(f',{ftp_site_name},{timestamp}\n'.encode('utf-8'))
        print('{{ftp_site_name} and {timestamp} written to local file')
    # Close file and connection
    local_file.close()
    conn.close()
    print('local file and connection closed')
    # Upload the file from the local temporary directory to S3
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_key = f'dt={timestamp}/{filename_convention}{yesterday}.txt'
    s3.upload_file(local_temp_file, Bucket=data_s3_bucket_name, Key=s3_key)
```

Logs from cloudwatch:

```
    2023-08-02T21:31:02.647-07:00   *cmd* 'CWD /SD1/Log'

2023-08-02T21:31:02.795-07:00   *resp* '250 CWD command successful.'

2023-08-02T21:31:02.795-07:00   opened local file

2023-08-02T21:31:02.795-07:00   *cmd* 'TYPE I'

2023-08-02T21:31:02.907-07:00   *resp* '200 Type set to I.'

2023-08-02T21:31:02.907-07:00   *cmd* 'PORT 169,254,76,1,145,9'

2023-08-02T21:31:03.062-07:00   *resp* '200 PORT command successful.'

2023-08-02T21:31:03.062-07:00   *cmd* 'RETR Data Log Trend_Ops_Data_Log_230802.txt'
```

It never gets to even writing the local file. I hope that is enough for @TimRoberts

Latest:

I added `conn.sendcmd('SITE CHMOD 777 ' + filename_convention + yesterday + '.txt')` to my script to test and it started working locally. I added the same script to AWS and there is STILL the only difference being the following:

Local:

```
*cmd* 'PORT 192,168,0,41,250,76'
```

AWS

```
*cmd* 'PORT 169,254,76,1,156,157'
```

This might mean there is some kind of networking setup issue on the AWS side that I need to research.

Comment: But you don't know whether it is the FTP RETR that times out or the S3 upload, which seems more likely to me.  S3 tends to be slowish.  More debug logging might help isolate that.  The numbers in the PORT command are just the IP address and port number being used.  They will vary.

Comment: except that 169.xxx.xxx.xxx are unrouteable IP addresses, so that is a bit of a problem maybe. I have another version of the script which tries to download to local tmp, that doesn't work either.

Comment: Added the other script for local temp and I also remembered that I have a second site I can test. It is in a completely different building. It is doing the same exact thing. I am baffled.

Comment: Why are you doing it without PASV? Firewalls and NAT often have trouble with non-passive FTP, so it's almost always better to use passive mode.

Comment: OK, but again, how do you know that it's the `retrbinary` call that is hanging, and not the `s3.upload_file`  You need more logging.

Comment: @Barmar for whatever reason these HMI panels don't make it available. I cannot change it. This is a built in server on C-More EA9 HMI panel.

Comment: @TimRoberts fair enough let me see what I can plug in to see where it is actually hanging. I have the logging level set to debug.

Comment: finally got more when I ripped pieces out to run locally. *cmd* 'RETR Data Log Trend_Ops_Data_Log_230801.txt'
*put* 'RETR Data Log Trend_Ops_Data_Log_230801.txt\r\n'
2023-08-02 22:29:11,688 ERROR __main__ 550 Data Log Trend_Ops_Data_Log_230801.txt: Requested action not taken.
*get* '550 Data Log Trend_Ops_Data_Log_230801.txt: Requested action not taken.\n'
*resp* '550 Data Log Trend_Ops_Data_Log_230801.txt: Requested action not taken.'

Comment: retrlines is not doing anything different. Though I noticed that Filezilla uses ASCII transfer.

Comment: 550 means file not found or permission error.  Are you sure that file name has spaces in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the answer is this is a convergence of the perfect edge case for not working.

1. The FTP is unable to use PASV and therefore is in an active transfer "mode"
2. Lambda is unable to receive TCP traffic, even if you manage to override the "PORT" setting from the ftplib.

So, if anyone ever manages to have this perfect storm again here is what I ended up doing:

I am working on another project for the same site that involves a RaspberryPi device. I moved this script, with a few other pieces, to the Pi and will be using it to retrieve the logs and then send to S3.

As for AWS options I did not explore but may have worked:

1. Smallest EC2 instance possible + VPC + IGW with Linux, Python, and CRON. Potentially you could maybe even use CDK and Code Deploy or something to manage it all.
2. ECS Fargate Networking Task. Way less familiar with this, but it might work.